# In $\mathbb{H}^2$, is there a basis such that $|(1, \pm \mathrm{i}) \cdot e_n| = 1/\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quaternions

### Physical intro

In quantum mechanics, [spin-½](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-%C2%BD) systems are described using **two-dimensional vectors**. In the physical experiment, we can measure the spin along three orthogonal axes X, Y, Z. Each of these axes has an associated **orthonormal basis**.

Let's say our first basis, associated with the axis X, is:
$$B = \big\{(1,0) ;\; (0,1)\big\}$$
If a particle in general orientation $v=(a,b)$ flies inside our measurement system. The probability we measure “X+” is:
$$ P = |B_1 \cdot v|^2 $$
Similarly, if we wanted to know the probability of measuring “X−”, it would be:
$$ P = |B_2 \cdot v|^2 $$

From the experiments we know that if a particle has spin either X+ or X− and we measure its spin along an orthogonal axis (eg. Y), the probability of measuring Y+ is 50 %, the same applies for Y−. That means that there is **no statistical correlation** between sping along X and Y.

### Mathematical intro

Motivated by the physics, we define:

---

Let $B$, $C$ be two orthonormal bases. We call them **uncorrelated** if $$ |b \cdot c|^2 = \frac{1}{2} $$ for all $b \in B, \; c \in C$.

---

It can be shown that if we work in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and start with the basis $B = \big\{(1,0) ;\; (0,1)\big\}$, there is only one basis that is uncorrelated to it:
$$ C = \Big\{ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \, (1, 1) ;\; \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \, (1, -1) \Big\}. $$
This is as far as we can get with $\mathbb{R}^2$. In a sense, this is a *complete set* of uncorrelated bases in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If we let ourselves work in $\mathbb{C}^2$, it turns out there is a third basis, uncorrelated to both $B$ and $C$:
$$ D = \Big\{ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \, (1, \mathrm{i}) ;\; \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \, (1, -\mathrm{i}) \Big\}. $$
Furthermore we can “turn” any of the bases by a factor of $e^{\mathrm{i}\varphi}$ without changing anything (ie. the bases will be still uncorrelated). However, this phase factor won't help us find a new basis uncorellated to $B, C, D$, so we're stuck with three uncorellated bases.

This is basically what we need in quantum mechanics, as our physical space has three spacial dimensions, so three uncorellated bases is just enough. However, what I'm interested in is, if we hypothetically needed a fourth basis, would [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) help?

### The question

If we work in $\mathbb{H}^2$, a two-dimensional [quaternionic Hilbert space](https://vixra.org/pdf/1411.0178v6.pdf), is there a set of **four pairwise uncorellated bases**? Specifically, is there an orthonormal basis $E$ such that it is uncorellated to $B, C, D$ defined earlier?

Comment: I know that the definition of uncorrelated bases was done without non-commutativity in mind, but since the inner product is sesquilinear, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: What scalars would you use? $\Bbb{H}$ isn't a field so you can't use them as scalars for a linear space.

Comment: I'm sorry, by „linear space“ I meant „the closest generalization that allows for quaternions“ ️ It turns out I also missed the inner product – ie. I need a quaternionic Hilbert space. I edited the question.